# l_dumpid = str('{:08x}'.format(l_dumpid)) ValueError: zero length field name in format

Tags: python, format, valueerror

```
l_dumpid = str('{:08x}'.format(l_dumpid))
```

ValueError: zero length field name in format

Any suggestions for fixing this ?

Am using python 2.7.8

Comment: l_dumpid is an integer value .. which i want in hex .. 

for ex .. l_dumpid is 55 ..  i want 00000037

Comment: Use `hex(i)` to get hex representation of `i`

Answer (score 0):

Use `hex(i)` to get hex representation of `i`

Example:

```
>>> hex(65)
'0x41'
```

**EDIT**

```
>>>a = 123
>>>'{:08x}'.format(a)
'0000007b'
```

`l_dumpid` is defined as an int and then you are changing it to `string`. I think that's what's causing the error. Otherwise this works fine.

Comment: Actually i dont want 0x41 .. i want 00000041 only

Answer (score 0):

Worked after using as below

l_dumpid = str('{0:08x}'.format(l_dumpid)).

Thanks for responses.